# Linux mint 17 cinnamon freezes after installing nvidia drivers?

Tags: nvidia, cinnamon

I Have **Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon** installed in my Laptop.
I Have **Nvidia**  **GForce** **610M** Graphic.
After installing Nvidia Drivers my Linux 17 Frequently Freezes Lot of Time.
Every time it Freezes , I must Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and must do:

> sudo service mdm restart

To Work Again.

Any suggestion to solve these Frequent Freezing problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue with my 660M.  Last night I tried installing `bumblebee` and it *seems* to have alleviated the issue. I used this (very crude) [tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1687). It will get you going in the right direction anyway.

Again, I can't 100% confirm that this is working, but it seems to be working. After following that, and restarting, I was on my laptop for a good 6 hours with no issue.